# Docker - Separate container or same container when adding binary for use by PHP?

Tags: php, docker, mediainfo

I'm looking for best practice guidance with the following scenario. I have an NGINX container and an FPM container. I would like to use the MediaInfo binary via a PHP wrapper. Should I:

A) Add the MediaInfo binary to the FPM container. Would this be appropriate as MediaInfo in not a long running process and PHP would effectively be using MediaInfo as a subprocess in a similar way to how PHP uses ImageMagick via a PECL extension i.e. PHP would halt and handover to MediaInfo until complete - there would not be 2 separate concurrent processes running within the same container.

B) Install MediaInfo binary on a separate container. If so, what would be the best was to integrate with MediaInfo from PHP? One solution would be to wrap MediaInfo in a RESTful interface, but this would then require a web server on the same container and in reality be no different to solution A.

C) Install MediaInfo binary on a separate container and call it directly from the FPM container (without a RESTful interface). Is there a way to do this that is secure?

D) Another solution that I've not detailed, as my Docker knowledge is limited!

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: As you're describing it in option A, adding the binary to a custom _image_ might be appropriate.